# Why doesn't an acid-base reaction occur in basic amide hydrolysis instead of nucleophilic acyl substitution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, nucleophilic-substitution, hydrolysis, grignard-reagent

In the reaction of Grignard reagent with a primary and secondary amide, nucleophilic acyl substiution doesn't happen. The reason given is that R- is a strong base as well as strong nucleophile, an acidic H is present in amide and finally, acid-base reactions are much faster than nucleophilic reactions. However, in basic amide hydrolysis, nucleophilic acyl substitution is able to occur despite OH- also being a strong base and nucleophile. Why doesn't the acid-base reaction occur here?

Comment: OH- is nowhere near as strong a base as a Grignard. Look up the pKa of a typical amide proton.

Comment: @Waylander AFAIK, amides are weak acids as well as weak bases. OH- is a(relatively) strong base and so the amide should react like an acid. Even, if the reaction is slower than that with Grignard, shouldn't it still be much faster than SN2th?

Comment: The pKa of a typical amide is around 20, OH- is not stronger enough to deprotonate it